# Enter Croatia first (before Schengen zone) with dual-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry, croatia

I am an Indian citizen and will be traveling to Croatia in a few days. I already have a multiple entry Schengen visa which is valid for the dates of my Croatia trip. However, my first destination from India will be Dubrovnik (Croatia) and after that I will depart for Schengen area (Austria).

Would I be able to enter Croatia before entering the Schengen zone?

Comment: Do you have a dual entry visa or a multiple entry visa?

Answer (score 4):

From the [VFS FAQ](http://www.vfsglobal.com/Croatia/India/faqs.html):

> If you hold a valid Schengen uniform visa (C) for two or multiple entries, valid for all Schengen Area member states, whose period of validity covers your stay in Croatia, and if you have not used all of the days in the Schengen Area (i.e. you need to have at least one day left of the approved number of days; and at least one entry in case of a double-entry visa), you do not require an (additional) Croatian visa for transit through or intended stays in the territory of the Republic of Croatia not exceeding 90 days in any 180-day period.