# Land first into Croatia with dual entry schengen

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, croatia

I have a dual entry schengen visa. I want to go to Croatia first and then Italy (for which i have the schengen visa) and leave to home country after that.
Is it possible to land into Croatia first using the dual entry schengen visa?

Apology for reposting but the answer was not clear from previous responses on post:

[Enter Croatia first (before Schengen zone) with dual-entry Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68825/enter-croatia-first-before-schengen-zone-with-dual-entry-schengen-visa)

Comment: The answer there is that you are fine without any additional visa, because you hold a Schengen visa which you can use to enter the Schengen Zone. (Not all used up.)

Comment: The answer to the previous post seems clear to me. What part do you find unclear?

Comment: Thanks for the response. So even entering a non schengen country first, despite the  schengen is not issued by that embassy, is OK, as long as it has an entry available! Thanks a ton.